# SAS date to category and date conversion

Tags: date, sas

I have two datasets of applications from two separate sources.  One has an application date in a MM/DD/YYYY format and the other in a datetime.  The dates then have to be classified as "Week X" where each week has a defined start date and end date that I will define in a separate dataset.  I have two questions:

1 - I always struggle with date to datetime conversions and vice-versa.  I will need this to combine the two datasets.  Any tips on doing this?  Which in the long run is easier to work with (I'm flexible in that regard)?

2 - To assign a week number to an application, would you maybe find the week number in the table that corresponds to the query result of select week_num where startdate >= app_date and app_date <= enddate; ?

This has been annoying.  Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can be easily done with datepart function; 
   http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245883.htm
2. Get week number from date. week function; 
   http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003154994.htm

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think the 2nd link is something I can work with for the weeks, though our week #1 is not the same as calendar week #1, but that can be adjusted.

The date conversion is what I'm having issues with.  I tried this:

    data IntApps;
    set IntApps;
    AddDateNew=datepart(AddDateNew);
    put AddDateNew Date9.;
    run;

AddDate is a DATETIME22.3 format and when I use the code above AddDateNew just comes back blank/periods.

Comment: Did You made a mistake? AddDateNew=datepart(AddDateNew); should be AddDateNew=datepart(AddDate);

Comment: Haha, yes. I was coming back to edit my post, but you caught it.  However I noticed that even with that, it returns a numeric variable.  I thought put AddDateNew Date9.; would take care of that.  I really hate dates in SAS.

Comment: put AddDateNew Date9.; only prints values to SAS log. 

Sas dates and datetime columns are numbers. For example 0 it is 1960.01.01 if date. So you get the values like that. Try add statement: format AddDateNew date9.;